# An incomplete understanding of Casting

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tableview and I would like to use the default cell.imageView to display a font-awesome image (which will be determined from a string in the core data object being displayed).
I am using [ios-Fontawesome](https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-fontawesome)

Essentially I am trying to establish the FAImageview (a subclass of UIImage) with the FA icon I would like and then make the cell ImageView display it.

The code below isn't working, but I have a suspicion that this should be allowed as they inherit from the same type.

However I also have a very incomplete understanding of casting.
Any assistance greatly appreciated.

My code (in my cellForRowAtIndexPath) is as follows.

```
FAImageView *faImageView = [[FAImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 100.f, 100.f)];
//FAImageView *faImageView = [[FAImageView alloc] init];
faImageView.image = nil;
[faImageView setDefaultIconIdentifier:@"fa-github"];

cell.imageView.image = faImageView.image;
```

Edit:
The setDefaultIconIdentifier appears as such:

```
- (void)setDefaultIconIdentifier:(NSString*)defaultIconIdentifier
{
self.defaultIcon = [NSString fontAwesomeEnumForIconIdentifier:defaultIconIdentifier];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the library code, your assumption is wrong.

Font awesome doesn't work with images at all, it works with fonts. The `UIImageView` doesn't actually have an image set. It has a label inside and setting the icon makes the text in that label changed.

That's why your code doesn't work - `faImageView.image` is supposed to be empty.

Personally I think this is a very poor library design.

Instead of using the default `imageView` of the cell, a better solution is to just `[cell.contentView addSubview:faImageView]` and set its frame.

Comment: According to this class, FAImageView is a UIImageView subclass, that's means if it has a image (show this image) if not it show the uilabel default icon, the problem of this guy is He using the image property but don´t point it to anything.

Comment: @OnikIV No, the problem is the poor design of the FA library. It has an image view which doesn't actually work with images at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
 cell.imageView.image = faImageView.image;
```

To this:

```
 cell.imageView = faImageView;
```

Or this:

```
 [cell.imageView addSubview:faImageView];
```

The problem is your instances of FAImageView doesn't have any image, your faImageView.image is equal to nil, You can try this to show:

```
 NSLog(@"Whats is my image:%@",[faImageView.image description]);
```